# How do I run a Ruby gem's specs?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rspec

I have forked a ruby gem and made some updates. I need to run the gem tests and add my new tests and ensure all tests are succeeding.

The forked ruby gem is using rspec tests. How can I run these test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually `rake` is sufficient to run all the tests, regardless of whether they're RSpec, Cucumber, etc. If you want to invoke RSpec directly try running `rspec spec` instead, or if the gem is using an unconventionally named test directory, just use `rspec <directory_name>`.

**Note:** Most new gems these days use Bundler to manage dependencies, so if you don't have the appropriate dependencies and there's a Gemfile in the root, then run "bundle install" first to get them. Then run with `bundle exec ...` (e.g., `bundle exec rspec spec`).

Comment: When I try `rspec spec`, I am receiving error 
`/home/mahmoud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require': no such file to load -- cover_me (LoadError)
 from /home/mahmoud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'
 from /home/mahmoud/work/fb_graph/spec/spec_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'"

Comment: I installed cover_me gem and it worked successfully. Thanks John.